# Show that $f \in L^1(\Bbb R) \Longleftrightarrow g \in L^1 (\Bbb R \times \Bbb R)$ where $g(x,y)=f(x+y)f(x).$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

***Problem:*** Show that $$f \in L^1(\Bbb R) \Longleftrightarrow g \in L^1 (\Bbb R \times \Bbb R)$$ where $g(x,y)=f(x+y)f(x).$

***Here is my solution, but there is one part that I believe I am convincing. In order to apply Tonelli we have to have $g$ to be measurable and nonnegative. In my answer I said $g$ is measurable because it is product of two measurable sets. This is true on a space but I am not sure it is true on a product spaces Any help how to prove $g$ is measurable? Thanks***

$"\Rightarrow"$ Let $f \in L^1(\Bbb R)$ which means that $f$ is integrable. First $g$ is a measurable function as a product of two measurable functions. By Tonelli theorem we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Bbb R}\int_{\Bbb R} |g(x,y)| dy dx &= \int_{\Bbb R}\int_{\Bbb R} |f(x+y) f(x)| dydx\\
&= \int_{\Bbb R} |f(x)|\Big[ \int_{\Bbb R} f(x+y)|dy \Big] dx\\
&=\int_{\Bbb R} |f(x)| \int_{\Bbb R} |f(y)|dy dx\\
&= \int_{\Bbb R}|f(x)|\cdot \|f\|_{L^1}\\
&= \|f\|_{L^1} \cdot \|f\|_{L^1}<\infty
\end{align*}
therefore $g \in L^1(\Bbb R \times \Bbb R)$. \

$"\Leftarrow"$ Consider now that $g \in L^1(\Bbb R \times \Bbb R)$ which means that $g$ is integrable on $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$. By Fubini theorem we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Bbb R}\int_{\Bbb R} |g(x,y)|dydx & = \int_{\Bbb R}\int_{\Bbb R} |f(x) f(x+y)| dy dx\\
&= \int_{\Bbb R} |f(x)| \Big[\int_{\Bbb R} |f(x+y)dy\Big] dx
\end{align*}
therefore $\int_{\Bbb R} |f(x+y)|dy $ is finite for a.e. $x$. Since Lebesgue measure is translation invariant we have $$\int_{\Bbb R} |f(x+y)| dy = \int_{\Bbb R} |f(x)| dy \text{ so } f \in L^1$$

Comment: I think your reasoning for $g$ is fine.  See Theorem 1.3 [in this document](https://sites.ualberta.ca/~rjia/Math417/Notes/chap5.pdf).